# What is the English word meaning "of low possibility"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example:

> — Do you think you can come?
>
> — Yeah, unless (word here) I have a visitor.

"not very likely" seems like a solution, but is there any other shorter word/phrase to use?

#### EDIT:

For those who want some more answers to this question, please refer to [this link on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/65835/22747).

Comment: about the only single word you could put in there is **bizarrely**

Comment: The example sentence would work with "unexpectedly" in the fill-in-the-blank spot. As it would with "by some miracle."

Comment: Perhaps "**by accident**" ...

Comment: @SvenYargs Wouldn't you normally transpose the "unexpectedly" and "I" in that instance?

Comment: @user867: Yes I would, but I thought I could get away with the suggestion as I baldly stated it, since transposition—though not identified as a permissible manipulation of the sentence—wouldn't make the resulting sentence any longer, so I would still be offering a "shorter word/phrase to use" that (after transposition) would be fully functional. But you are certainly right that, in the example sentence, "unless I unexpectedly have a visitor" sounds far more natural than "unless unexpectedly I have a visitor." Even more natural might be "unless I have an unexpected visitor."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual idiomatic form is to say something like:

*I shall be available, **except in the unlikely event** I have a visitor*.

Comment: not the solution of one word, but it sounds very natural. thanks!

Comment: @technophile I think *except* is better, so I have edited my 'answer'.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't "unlikely" do? i.e. "It's unlikely!"

Comment: Yeah it could, but it sounds a bit "of a very low possibility" *or* "seemingly not happening"... doesn't it?

Comment: Well, if you do not want a word that means "of low possibility" then you should change your title.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you reread my comment? I said it sounds "of a **very** low possibility", not "of low possibility", which is my question, so I guess I don't need to change my title unless you think the two are equal.

Comment: @technophyle- I think this is where individuals each bring slightly different interpretations of relative ordering.  I think *unlikely* is *exactly* the right word for *of low probability*  ***very*** low probability is closer to *improbable* in my book.  Of course *unlikely* will not fit in to your sentence without some extra words or a bit of rearrangement.

Answer (score 2):

> — Do you think you can come?
>
> — Yes, unless I were to have a visitor.

This means it's unlikely I'll have a visitor.  But if you think your listener might not understand that, you could say *Yes, unless I were to have a visitor, which isn't very likely;* OR *Yes, except in the unlikely event I were to have a visitor.*

Here's a clearer one that's still very succinct: *Yes, unless I were to have a surprise visitor.*

If you don't want this fancy subjunctive, you could say: *Yes, unless a surprise visitor shows up.*  (This is the one I would probably use -- nice and simple and clear.)

Answer (score 0):

*not very likely*

Not one word, but that sounds more likely than unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to think of single word answers that fit into the sentence given.

You could try "possibly" or "perhaps".

Answer (score 0):

I would reword the response.

> — Do you think you can come?
>   — ***Most likely*** yes, unless I have a visitor.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***improbably***?  It has the correct meaning, and moreover it's an adverb, so it can fit in your sentence (modifying *have*).